# High CPU usage on SQL server - Slow queries

Tags: sql-server, performance

Our MS SQL Server is using about 95% of the CPU-power.

After a server (hardware) restart, or a SQL-Service restart, the usage is 0% and slowly increases over the course of 1-3 days. Depending on how much it is used.

When it's over 80%, every query is extremely slow.

Our website is dealing with alot of big queries, so some of them takes 45-60 seconds. 
After a restart (CPU usage less than 80%), it takes 11-20 seconds for the same Query.

---

How can I fix this? I've read online that affinity masks can adjust the CPU usage, but the Affinity settings are disabled. I cannot change them. **Is this because I only have 1 processor?**

There are plenty of tricks to do with the queries themselves, but our websites and services are quite big, and there is simply too much to change.

Most of them are already pretty well optimized anyway.

---

I cannot keep restarting the SQL-Service, even though it only takes 2 seconds, because we have an alarm service that allows people to call in and record a message, a selected group will then be called and hear the recorded message.

This system is used by hundreds Search and Rescue teams, and if the SQL-Service restarts during an alarm, it will terminate and the person that called it in will not be notified.

---

I have searched all over the place, but found nothing except for stuff about "Affinity Masks", which I cannot change.

**There must be a way to clear out the CPU cache, without terminating current queries... right?**

---

```
SQL: Microsoft SQL Server 11.0.2100.60
OS: Windows Server 2012 x64
Processor: 2.30 GHz
RAM: 4.00 GB
```